# Configuring my own gem: via DSL? Or *.yml config file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When building my own gem, what are the procs and cons to allow a user to configure it via

```
a) DSL or ruby code 
vs
b) *.yml config file
```

?

For me, they're about the same.

Comment: It depends. What does your gem do? How much and what kind of configuration does it need?

Comment: Pros: it is configurable, Cons: None. Unless the ability to configure breaks your gem. (Hint: Your question right now is actually what are the pros and cons of allowing a user to configure the gem? Not what are the pros and cons of each technique.) Either way not really suited for SO

Comment: @MátéSolymosi, in what cases the 1st approach is better, in what the 2nd one?

Answer (score 0):

Using a DSL or Ruby code for configuration means that someone using your library doesn't have to conform to your expectations for how those bits of configuration should be stored and managed. YML files may be common, but so are ENV variables.

If you only offer a YML configuration option, then please consider running the YML file through ERB (like Rails) so that folks can reference ENV variables according to their preference.